# adb devices gives same serial number for all Micromax devices

Tags: adb, multiple-devices, micromax

I have few micromax devices and I have different serial number for those in the box. But when I run the command adb devices for these devices, I get everything as 0123456789ABCDEF. Is there are way to get the proper device serial number for these micromax devices?

Comment: What do you mean by Serial number? I mean are you referring to IMEI?

Comment: The number that we see when we run "adb devices". The same number can be seen in the box in most of the other phones as "S/n". Ideally they both should be same.

Comment: You can try this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209020/serial-number-got-changed-after-factory-reset

Answer (score -1):

your problem may be incorrect drivers. if you installed correct drivers then restart adb and your phone too. if this does not help im sure you're not installed correct drivers. hope this help.