# Serial Number Got Changed After Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset

After "Factory Resetting" my tablet I realized that the serial Number was changed (it is now a weird number 0123456789ABCDEF).

**Edit March 17 2019**

This is the number that shows when I do adb devices. As far as I know this is the serial number and not the Android ID.

**End Edit**

Why did this happen?
How do I go about returning it to its original SN?
How do I prevent it from happening again?

I have seen some options of changing the SN number but I'm reluctant to try them since the programs they use doesn't look like official (safe) programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serial # is provided by the Linux Gadget driver. Depending on your kernel version it's either in

- /config/usb_gadget/g1/strings/0x40*/serialnumber

  or
- /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial

Since you're rooted, you can easily change the number by writing to this "file" - which is really just a parameter that the driver will digest and export accordingly.

While you're at it, there are other cool strings there, like Manufacturer and Product , which you can mess with, and similar "files" containing USB identification, and controlling the device persona (Mass storage, MTP, PTP, etc)

Comment: The second option is on my device but the file is named `iSerial`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the "Android ID". This Android ID is a 15 or 16 characters long ID exactly like the example in your question.

The Android ID is not device specific and is stored in the user data section. It is a random number, usually generated the device boots the first time.
This also applies to the first time the device is booted after a factory reset because the factory reset has deleted all user data including the old Android ID.

> Why did this happen?

You did a factory reset.

> How do I go about returning it to its original SN?

The Android ID can not be changed on a regular non-rooted device. With root permissions it is easy, as it is stored in an SQLite database file on your system. - assuming you know the old Android ID. See also this question: [How to back up my current Android ID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47184).

> How do I prevent it from happening again?

Do not perform a factory reset.

Comment: You can change the Android ID using adb. `adb shell settings put secure android_id "YOUR_ID"`. Content command can also be used for this. BTW, I am quite certain OP is talking about `ro.serialno` (which you get to see when running `adb devices` on a USB connected Android to PC). OP is using an MTK device, and given their earlier question about the same device I am assuming OP flashed the firmware. I once flashed the firmware of an MTK device and ended up with the same serial number. It doesn't hurts, just looks weird. :)

Comment: I am talking about the number that shows when I run adb devices. I have done a factory reset on this device as well as other devices and never had a problem with this serial number changing. @Firelord Is there a way to repair this number to its original number? I do know the original number and my device is rooted. I would prefer to be able to do it on the device itself if at all possible.